# Show that $\alpha(r_{1} + r_{2}) \leq \alpha(2r_{1}) + \alpha( 2r_{2})$ for a class $\kappa$ function

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $\alpha$ be a class $\kappa$ function on $[0,a)$. Show that 
>   $$\alpha(r_{1} + r_{2}) \leq \alpha(2r_{1}) +  \alpha(2r_{2}), \quad\forall r_1,r_2 \in [0,a/2)$$

**Attempted solution**
From the definition of a class [$\kappa$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_kappa_function) we know that $\alpha$ is a strictly increasing function meaning that the following should hold
$$\alpha(r_{1} + r_{2}) \leq \alpha(2r_{1}+2r_{2})$$
I want to show that 
$$\alpha(2r_{1} +  2r_{2}) \leq \alpha(2r_{1}) +  \alpha(2r_{2})$$

This would be true if $\alpha$ is linear, however, since there are other non-linear functions that are class $\kappa$ e.g. $\arctan(x)$ I don't know if this arguments holds.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $$r_1+r_2\le \max\{r_1+r_1,r_2+r_2\}=\max\{2r_1,2r_2\} $$ The restriction $r_1,r_2< a/2$ ensures that $2r_1,2r_2 \in [0,a)$.

Comment: Thank you. I think I see it now!